# Can I add my router's mac address in the whitelist and allow any device connected to it to connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

So my landlord provided a LAN on our room but only allows us to add only 1 mac address to be whitelisted.

I bought an AP router and whitelisted the router's mac address thinking any device to connect to it can connect to the internet. It's seems it's not working. I tried to give my laptop's mac address (connected to the router i bought) and it connects to the internet.

Is there any way I can allow all devices connected to the router to connect to the internet?

Comment: Sounds like what you have is (purely) an AP, but not a router. (Like you got a switch, but wireless.) (Or you made it operate in the AP-only mode.)

Comment: @tomyan or he programmed the lan mac address rather then the wan one.

Comment: make sure you plug the ethernet your landlord provided to your WAN port of the AP router, not the LAN port.

Comment: Thanks guys! Seems the case is that what I have is a wifi repeater with an AP mode. I bought this since it's small and can be wall plugged to save space. Looks like I need to buy a decent router.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MAC addresses are associated with interfaces  so you need to provide the WAN Interface MAC address to the landlords device.

You need to ensure your AP router is set up in router mode - which, practically speaking, means you need to run NAT and use a network different to the landlords. (eg if he is using 192.168.x.x, you may want to use 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x)

Comment: Thanks! Seems the case is that what I have is a wifi repeater with an AP mode. I bought this since it's small and can be wall plugged to save space. Looks like I need to buy a decent router.

Comment: It's really just "practically speaking" that NAT is relevant here though, since the source MAC address will the router's as long as it "routes" (i.e. forwards L3 traffics between two interfaces).

Comment: @TomYan there is more to it then that - ss soon as the router us routing it is forwarding packets it doesnt own  and blocking dhcp (unless it is proxying it), so unless the landlord is subnetting and routing, traffic wont be routed back unless nat us used - and Imagine way  way less then 1 in 100 landlords would subnet in that way.

Comment: I know. That's why I didn't deny that "practically speaking" it's still true. It's just I don't think it's a good way to put it as it leads to misconception (like NAT not only masquerade your IP but also MAC address). You need NAT, but missing NAT is not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: @TomYan agreed.